# SQLMAP post data error persists even after changing the requested file

Tags: linux, sql-injection, sqlmap

I was trying to run sqlmap with method POST but I got this error:

```
[CRITICAL] no parameter(s) found for testing in the provided data (e.g. GET parameter 'id' in 'www.site.com/index.php?id=1')
```

even though I have provided the parameter in the request

```
sqlmap -r variablespatch.txt --dbs --batch --data variable_id
```

[image: data used in the request]

above is the image of the data I have used in the request

I have tried changing formatting also multiple times but it was not working.
`sqlmap -r variablespatch.txt --dbs --batch --p variable_id` I've tried with this request also

Comment: sqlmap -r variablespatch.txt --dbs --batch --p variable_id         I've tried with this request also

Comment: To add information, [`Edit`](/posts/76463262/edit) your post. To present text, copy&paste into a block quote rather than use an image of the text rendered.

Answer (score 0):

the header format you are using is not correct.
you must put the post parameter under two newlines
ex :

Accept-Language: en-Us, en;q=0.9

{"variable_id":"tjdm4k1o"

Comment: Consider using code blocks in your answers.